# Onenote graph API bug in programmatically updated task

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api, microsoft-graph-onenote

I am using OneNote graph API to update a task using golang. Below is my approach:

[image]

After that whatever I try to create like a new task or anything, this same data-id is added to the new tasks or elements. For example, I have updated the task "Card 2" programmatically and added data-id. This same data-id is being added to each below elements.

[image]

Any help would be really appreciated.